# \ifmmode doesn't seem to work correctly inside an array environment

Tags: math-mode, conditionals

I’m struggling with getting `\ifmmode` to work correctly when used inside an `array` environment which is inside a `displaymath` environment.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\signal}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    1#1
  \else
    2$#1$
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \signal{a} \signal{b} & \signal{c} \signal{d} \\
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

This example generates the following output:

> [image: 2a 1 _b_ 2c 1 _d_]

Why doesn’t all invokations of `\signal` detect math-mode?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At the start of an alignment cell, TeX is looking for an `\omit` or `\noalign`, rather than being in math mode. The way to deal with this is to insert a `\relax`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\signal}[1]{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    1#1
  \else
    2$#1$
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \signal{a} \signal{b} & \signal{c} \signal{d} \\
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Now, the issue with that is that it will mess up kerning if used in other places (it puts a `\relax` in even when it's not needed). In some LaTeX3 work, we've experimented with an approach to 'pick up' the alignment cell using e-TeX. At one point we had something very elaborate to test for this

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\signal}[1]{%
  \ifnum\currentgrouptype = 6 %
    \ifnum\lastnodetype = 0 %
    \else
      \ifnum\lastnodetype = 7 %
      \else
        \relax
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \ifmmode
    1#1
  \else
    2$#1$
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \signal{a} \signal{b} & \signal{c} \signal{d} \\
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

This uses the various diagnostics from e-TeX to pick up the start of a cell. However, this is really not a good idea as it pretends to be expandable but does insert `\relax`: not expandable! A much cleaner approach is to use `\protected`

```
\documentclass{article}

\protected\def\signal#1{%
  \ifmmode
    1#1
  \else
    2$#1$
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \signal{a} \signal{b} & \signal{c} \signal{d} \\
  \end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

as e-TeX does not expand protected macros here.

Comment: Joseph, we're *not* in math mode: that will be started when TeX inserts the *u* part for the cell (in the terminology of the TeXbook) and ended with the *v* part. Saying `\omit` won't give math mode, for example; LaTeX takes precautions to add again the `$` characters when `\multicolumn` is used in an `array`. But this is almost splitting hairs, I guess. :)