# How do I make a macro require math mode?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have defined a macro that I would like to be used exclusively in math mode. In order to enforce this, I would like the macro to throw an error message whenever it is used outside of math mode. **What is the easiest way of making a macro math-mode-only?**

Comment: You can use `\ifmmode`, or use `ensuremath` so that it'll be in math mode.

Comment: @PeterGrill I would like to forbid the use of my macro outside of math mode.

Comment: Related Question: [How to define a macro conditionally based on whether it is being used in text mode or math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106618/how-to-define-a-macro-conditionally-based-on-whether-it-is-being-used-in-text-mo).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `\ifmmode` to check if you are in math mode, and trigger an error if not. An attempt to use it outside of math mode yields:

> Attempt to use \MyMathModeMacro outside of math mode.
>
> See my preamble documentation for explanation.
>
> Type  H   for immediate help.
>
> l.16 \MyMathModeMacro
>                        % <--- This will produce an error
>   ?

### Notes:

- As David Carlisle pointed out, need to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand` to avoid premature expansion. See [\ifmmode doesn't seem to work correctly inside an array environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/ifmmode-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-inside-an-array-environment).
- If you want to allow the macro to be used in or outside of math mode, you can use `\ensuremath` to typeset the content in math mode. But you should refer to [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro) before doing this.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MyMathModeMacro}{%
    \ifmmode
         E = m c^2
    \else
        \GenericError{\space\space\space\space}
            {Attempt to use \@backslashchar MyMathModeMacro outside of math mode}
            {See my preamble documentation for explanation.}
            {Need to use either use inline or display math.}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\MyMathModeMacro$

\MyMathModeMacro% <--- This will produce an error
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I think you are right (have corrected), but surprisingly `PackageError` does not issue a `PackageError` if it does not get 3 parameters??

Comment: @PeterGrill That was fast! I am wondering, is there a way of throwing an error in a way that doesn't make it look package-specific? (I might simply have defined this macro in my preamble.)

Comment: I normally just use `\typeout{message}\QUITHERE`, where `\QUITHERE` is not defined, but thought I would use the official way of reporting errors.  Alternatively, you could use `my preamble`, or some other relevant text as the first parameter to `\PackageError`.

Comment: @PeterGrill you can use `\GenericError` (four arguments).

Comment: You'll need to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` not `\newcommand` or you will get the wrong answer at the start of array cells.

Comment: @user14996: Have updated to use `GenericError` so that it does not appear to be a package error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, have updated solution.

Comment: @PeterGrill The first argument (see [macros2e.pdf](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/info/macros2e/macros2e.pdf)) is for continuation text (to be invoked by the `\MessageBreak` command within the other arguments, as I understand).

Comment: @user14996: Thanks. Have replaced that with spaces.  Anything better you can think of to put in there?

Comment: @PeterGrill Hmm, I'm new to this, but I thought that one can simply leave the first argument empty: unless I use `\MessageBreak` explicitly, the first argument won't be invoked. But do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am new to `GenericError` as well. But from the doc you provided, having it there should not a problem. In case one decides to expand the message and add a `\MessageBreak`, then it is all ready to go.