# Define symbols differently in text mode versus math mode

Tags: math-mode, conditionals, text-mode

I'd like to define `\a` to be the `$\forall$` symbol, but I'd like it be the regular `$\forall$` in text-mode and `\mathsmaller{\forall}` in math mode.  Is there any easy way to do this? I'm guessing it should be easy with some TeX programming but I've never done that!

CORRECTION:  I misstated what I want to do; long day and my brain is tired.  What I really want to do is have $\forall$ display smaller when it's a subscript.  So I want to write sentences like "Let $(\K_\fa, \leq_\fa)$ be the $\fa$-closure of ..."  and have the first \fa display in regular size but the second display using \mathsmaller

Comment: Don't, there is no reason to do this.

Comment: Note that using single-character macros like `\a` conflicts with other macros in some cases. I'd suggest using something more descriptive, even if its using `\fa`.

Comment: Don't redefine `\a`. You'll regret it, sooner or later. What's a reason for this strange requirement? The “for all” symbol should never appear in text mode.

Comment: Please see correction above; I misstated my question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I do `\newcommand{\fa}{\forall}` and type `Let $(\K_\fa, \leq_\fa)$ be the $\fa$-closure`, the result is as expected: the “for all” in subscripts is smaller than the one in `$\fa$-closure`.

Comment: @egreg:  I'd like it even smaller; the default feels a little too big for me.  Sorry for the lack of clarity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\ifmmode` to check for math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}

\protected\def\a{%
  \ifmmode%
    \mathsmaller{\forall}
  \else%
    $\forall$
  \fi}

\begin{document}
  in text: \a and in math: $\a$
\end{document}
```

See [\ifmmode doesn't seem to work correctly inside an array environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/ifmmode-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-inside-an-array-environment) for the reason why to put `\protected`.

Comment: Thanks for this!  It looks like the right answer to the question I asked but not the question I meant to ask.  Not sure what  the protocol is for accepting answers in that context?

Comment: @user3054726: [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "[Ask Question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.