# Changing symbol size when used as subscript

Tags: math-mode, conditionals, subscripts

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276633/define-symbols-differently-in-text-mode-versus-math-mode).

I'd like to define `\fa` to display `\forall` when typed as usual but be `\mathsmaller{\forall}` when `\fa` is used as a subscript.  For example, I want to write sentences like

```
Let $(\K_\fa, \leq_\fa)$ be the $\fa$-closure of ...
```

and have the first `\fa` display in regular size but the second display using `\mathsmaller`.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do nothing different from

```
\newcommand{\fa}{\forall}
```

Let's try it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fa}{\forall}

\begin{document}

Let $(K_\fa, {\leq}_\fa)$ be the $\fa$-closure of whatever.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the braces around `\leq` when it's not used as a relation symbol, but as the name of the relation. Of course you'll continue to write

```
$a \leq_\fa b$
```

when the symbol is used in its proper sense.

You *might* do

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fa}{{
  \mathchoice{\forall}{\forall}{\scriptscriptstyle\forall}{\forall}
}}

\begin{document}

Let $(K_\fa, {\leq}_\fa)$ be the $\fa$-closure of whatever.

\end{document}
```

but the result would look very dubious.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  The second one is exactly what I want.  It actually looks better to me; maybe I've just been staring at these too long.

I think the reason is that I often subscript \K and \leq with letters; so with this solution the symbol \forall as a subscript looks about the  same size as the letter 'd' for example