# amsmath's align* or gather* followed by \ifmmode = 

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, mathtools, gather

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}%%% or amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \ifmmode Math\else Text\fi
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

to any of the four LaTeX processors (latex, pdflatex, xelatex, lualatex) prints “Text”. The same holds if `\ifmmode` starts the body of a macro called right after `\begin{gather*}`. The same holds if `\begin{gather*}` is replaced with `\begin{align*}`, `\[\begin{aligned}`, or even `\[\begin{aligned}[t]`, or even `\[\begin{aligned}[t] stuff &`, each time properly terminated, of course.

Why? Who is the culprit and what to do?

Comment: At the beginning of an alignment cell, `\ifmmode` is always false. Add `\relax` in front of it.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks! The answer in the question you mentioned (namely, prepend `\protected` to `\def`) works if `\ifmmode` is hidden inside the macro, and, of course, that question itself specifically mentions both an `array` and a macro, therefore being not a duplicate of my original post.

Comment: I am reopening the question because StackExchange's interface said “This question already has an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27592/ifmmode-doesnt-seem-to-work-correctly-inside-an-array-environment”. Clearly, this is not the case: the linked post is related but does not contain an answer to the current question. The real answer to the current question is provided by @egreg in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650863 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All alignment display environment of `amsmath` are defined in terms of the primitive `\halign` with suitable templates for the column cells.

By design, as soon as TeX starts examining a new cell in an `\halign` it is in “restricted horizontal mode” and recursively expands the first token it finds, in order to see whether `\omit` appears at the beginning, which would trigger not to use the specified template; usually, `\omit` is followed by `\span` in order to merge cells, but that's not mandatory.

In your case, TeX expands `\ifmmode` and this conditional turns out to be false, because TeX is *not* in math mode. It would only be true after the *u* part (what should go before the cell text) has been inserted.

Add `\relax` in front of `\ifmmode`. But of course your conditional text would be inserted by a macro: use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for defining it.

Thus either

```
\newcommand{\mymacro}{\relax\ifmmode Math\else Text\fi}
```

or

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mymacro}{\ifmmode Math\else Text\fi}
```

The latter is preferable if `\mymacro` can also appear in moving arguments. It works because a macro defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` expands to something preceded by `\protect` and, in typesetting contexts, `\protect` is the same as `\relax`.

As an aside, for macros without argument using `\newcommend` or `\newcommand*` is irrelevant. The difference shows only for macros with arguments, where the `*`-form disallows `\par` (or empty lines) in any argument. The same applies to `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Comment: Thx! Would `\DeclareRobustCommand*` have the same property as `\DeclareRobustCommand` in this respect?

Comment: @GeekestGeek With the `*`-form, `\par` or empty lines are not allowed in the argument (if any). Otherwise, there's no difference.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, `\DeclareRobustCommand*` changed the visual appearance compared to `\newcommand*` in a larger, non-minimal example. However, the change was so small that I couldn't see the difference, although `diffpdf` drew my attention to its existance.

Comment: @GeekestGeek A macro defined with `\newcommand` (with or without `*`) is expandable and you incur in the untimely expansion of `\ifmmode` unless you precede it with `\relax`. I added explanations.